# TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE not fired on MS Surface

Tags: actionscript-3, windows-8, air, touch

I'm developing an AIR app prototype on Surface, and I'm noticing that TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE is not fired as expected....

I've built a quick debug application:

```
private var tf:TextField;

        public function init():void{
            trace("init");
            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
            tf = new TextField();
            tf.multiline = true;
            tf.width = 800;
            tf.height = 2000;
            this.stage.addChild(tf);
            tf.text = "Test";

            var touch:Sprite = new Sprite;
            touch.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF00,0.3);
            touch.graphics.drawRect(0,0,800,200);
            touch.graphics.endFill();
            this.stage.addChild(touch);


            touch.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, updateTF);
            touch.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, updateTF);
            touch.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, updateTF);
            touch.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_OVER, updateTF);
            touch.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, updateTF);
            touch.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_ROLL_OUT, updateTF);
            touch.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_ROLL_OVER, updateTF);

        }

        private function updateTF(event:TouchEvent):void
        {
            trace(event);
            tf.appendText("\n event:" + event);
        }
```

...and it confirms me no TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE is being fired.

What could be the issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I didn't solve the issue but I found the explication and a workaround.
This is bug on AIR 3.8 on Windows 8.
Just install a previous version of AIR.
Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MouseEvents` instead of `touch events` for Microsoft Surface. Because adobe not yet released for Microsoft Surface touch device(see adobe labs).

Normally all touch events fall back to mouse events so you can try with Mouse-events. It works well for me . But not sure about Mouse Move event but it works for touch begin and touch end events to mousedown and mouseup events.

Comment: Thx Raja, I was working with MouseEvents but Mouse_Move doesn't work. I was trying to switch to Touch Event to try to solve this issue

Comment: Is it out of the question to simply monitor mouse X and Y and fire your own mouseMove events?